# View HTML file directly vs. downloading as attachment

Tags: box-api

We have paid Box.com accounts.  Our users occasionally want to upload complex HTML files to these sites to share with customers, as they don't have access to an internet-facing web host.

The HTML files are self-contained in that they have no references to other files in the box account.  That is, all scripts, css, and images are publicly-accessible.

Using the Direct Link method of Box, the users can send the URLs to the client.  However, when the clients access the link, the HTML files are downloaded as attachments, vs. being viewed "inline" in the browser.  This causes the files not to function like a normal HTML file on mobile devices, because the attachment triggers a different viewer other than the standard browser.

What we'd like to do is literally open that HTML file right in the browser using the direct link.  Is there anyway to override the forcing of HTML files downloading as attachments?

Comment: Hey Chris, It is not clear to me if there is a problem with Box API or rather Box Mobile website. Have you tried dedicated mobile apps? It believe if you'd send shared link to users, they should be able to preview HTML files on their mobile devices with Box apps (such as Box for iPhone / iPad or Box for Android, etc).

Comment: Hi Boris, I think the issue is that the HTML file we are trying to share has embedded script and css. The Box viewer (I guess it uses Crocococ?) does not properly render those files.  What we'd like to do is provide the user a link to the HTML file, and then they  view the file directly in the browser they used to open the link - not open it in a 'viewer' and not force its download as an attachment, which it does on PC browsers and Android phones.

Comment: I'm a little more confused now.  I am looking at this article:

https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200519908-Direct-Linking

and it says:

"Direct links end with the file's extension type. Therefore, if you are linking to a Microsoft Word document, a direct link will end with *.doc."

I have an Enterprise account, and yet I don't see the option to share the file with the extension intact like that.

Comment: I'd suggest that you file support ticket with Box.

Comment: Thanks; I did do that.  As a correction to anyone else reading, I misspoke earlier.  The Box "direct link" to our HTML file does have the extension intact; however, box forces the download as an attachment.  It does NOT do this for direct links to e.g. images, though, which render in the browser as expected.  So, Box does have the capability to deliver files inline and not as attachments.  Hopefully it's just a matter of getting it enabled.

Comment: I'm adding this comment for anyone else who is looking for this functionality.  Box product management has decided not to implement it for HTML files. The Box Preview function renders the HTML to PDF and then converts it back to HTML (of course you will lose scripts this way).  The direct link opens as an attachment, no exceptions.  This is obviously a non-starter for people on most mobile devices.  Dropbox will allow it via public folders, but Box does not.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question and found only one other post on this, but unanswered. Trying to view html files (with this time links to images, CSS, javascript, etc) in BOX'es viewer fails. Did you come across a work-around yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It can not be rectified directly in Box. What we had to do is set up an intermediate server and pass the Box URL in as a parameter. The server then retrieves the file and serves it inline like we need it to. Big workaround and not ideal at all.